# I am getting an ArrayIndexOutoBound exception when trying to build a tree

Tags: java, arrays, exception, recursion, syntax-error

I dont understand why im getting an an arrayindexoutofbounds exception.

This is my code below. The bit that is causing issue i think is in the addnode method

```
import java.io.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;
import java.util.*;


class Tree 
{
    Node root;
    class Node
    {
        int data;
        int id;
        Node parent;
        List<Node> children;


        public Node(int d, int i, List<Node> k)
        {
            this.data = d;
            this.id = i;
            this.children = k;
        } 
    }
    Node addNode(int[][] treetxt, Tree tree, int n)
    {
        System.out.println(n);
        List<Node> k = new ArrayList<Node>();
        if(treetxt[2][n-1] != 0)
        {
            for(int i=2; i!=0; i++)
            {
                 k.add(addNode(treetxt, tree, treetxt[i][n]));
            }
        }

        return new Node(n,treetxt[1][n],k); 
    }
}

class DSAP3
{
    int n;
    List<Tree.Node> all = new ArrayList<Tree.Node>();
    Tree club = new Tree();
    int[][] treedata;



    public static void main(String [ ] args)    
    {
        DSAP3 tourney = new DSAP3();
        String line;
        File file = new File("P3eg1.txt");
        try 
        {   
            Scanner in = new Scanner(file);
            tourney.n = in.nextInt();
            tourney.treedata= new int[tourney.n][tourney.n];
            line = in.nextLine();
            for(int y=0; y<tourney.n; y++)
            {
                line = in.nextLine();
                Scanner lineread = new Scanner (line);
                int x = 2;
                tourney.treedata[0][y]=lineread.nextInt();
                tourney.treedata[1][y]=lineread.nextInt();
                lineread.next();
                while(lineread.hasNextInt())
                {
                    tourney.treedata[x][y]=lineread.nextInt();
                    x++;
                }
            }
            tourney.club.root = tourney.club.addNode(tourney.treedata, tourney.club, 1);            

       }    
       catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error opening the file ");
            System.exit(0);
        }               





   }
}
```

The exception is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at Tree.addNode(DSAP3.java:28)
at Tree.addNode(DSAP3.java:32)
at DSAP3.main(DSAP3.java:77)
```

Before the exception is thrown the print statement in the add nodes method prints 1 and then 0

How can i fix this
Thanks in advance

Comment: Which line is line 28 of DSAP3.java?

Comment: Which line is line 28?

Comment: for(int i=2; i!=0; i++) This seems to be infinite...

Comment: `treetxt[2][n-1]` You say `n == 0` at some point. Thus `n - 1 == -1` Causing an index out of bounds exception